# Is it mention in vedas that we have to merge with supreme God after we have broken the cycle of rebirth. Please give reference

Tags: vedas

Is it mention in vedas that we have to merge with भ्रमण after we have broken the cycle of rebirth. Please give reference.

Comment: What is भ्रमण, I guess you mean 'Brahman'?

Comment: We have to realize Self, not merge as we are already That (not for animals or materialist atheists), hence its called Self-realization or Brahmgyan or Atmangyan and the final concluded mahavakya of Upanishads 'Aham Brahmāsmi'.